# fail jasmine test if it take too much time

Tags: jasmine

I'm using the jasmine standalone (no karma)
I have a simple test executing a function and expecting a result :

```
  it("...", function() {
    expect(f(x)).toBe(y);
  });
```

How can I make this test failing with a specific error message if the f() function take more than X millisecond to execute?

Thanks

Comment: Is `f()` async?

Comment: No it is not async.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small test that might help you

```
require('jasmine');

function slow(n) {
    let timer = 10000000000;
    while(timer--) {
        // do nothing, just waiting
    }
    return n;
}

describe('My test', () => {
    it('test slow function', (done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done.fail('Running to much time');
        }, 10000);

        expect(slow(1)).toBe(1);

        done();
    });
});
```

The `slow` function in my example can be your `f` function. So, the idea is, if `slow` it is not `async` then the code will wait until it finished, so, we can use the `async` functionality of `jasmine`, just declare that we receive a `done` callback or returning a `Promise`, then `jasmine` will wait for `done` to be executed or the `Promise` to be resolved.

The code in my pc run in 12s, but if it takes 10s, I call `done.fail()`.

If you have in your `jasmine`'s config `"stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": true`, then the test will stop immediately after calling `done.fail()`.

See a few examples of [async tests](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async).

Hope it helps